# How can I access pair

Tags: c++, std-pair

```
unordered_map<T, pair<int, T>> _sets;
```

Let's say I have a key called _key, how can I access the data in the unordered_map? How can I get the data type T and int from the pair<>?

Comment: `_sets[_key].first` and `_sets[_key].second`?

Comment: @cad Has the answer. If you want both, consider `auto& data = _sets[_key];` to avoid looking it up twice.

Answer (score 0):

```
T myT = _sets[_key].first;
pair<int, T> myPair = _sets[_key].second;

int fromPairInt = myPair.first;
T fromPairT = myPair.second;
```

fast access:

```
 int fromPairInt = (_sets[_key].second).first;
    T fromPairT = (_sets[_key].second).second;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "fast access"? Your solution is not fast as it performs two lookups.

Comment: when you save object to another one the copy c'tor will work,
fast access save copy and memory!